# Minimum path cover in a DAG

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

Given a directed acyclic graph $G=(V,A)$ and a set $A'$ of $A$. It is well known that searching for a minimum number of vertex-disjoint paths that cover all the vertices of $G$ can be solved in polynomial time. Will the problem remain polynomial if we add the constraint that each path should contain at least one edge of $A'$?